# Tomcat Parallel Deployment New Sessions being created

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

We are using the Tomcat Parallel deployment for our main monolithic app, which works great.  The question I have is, we are noticing is that the old application can stay around for up to a week with active sessions.  Digging into it further using the Tomcat Manager page we have been noticing new users are starting new sessions in the old version and not migrating to the newly deployed app.  So my question is:

Why are new sessions being created in the old version of the application.

Updated:
Apache Tomcat 8.5.35 using OpenJdk 1.8, behind a BigIP F5

Comment: Tomcat version?
Is there any sort of load-balancer between the user agents and Tomcat?

Comment: @MarkThomas We are currently using Apache Tomcat 8.5.35 (openjdk 1.8) behind a BigIP F5

Comment: Hmm. To map to an older version, the client has to present a session ID that is still valid for the older version of the application. I don't see a way to force a new session for an old version. How are you determining that a new session is being created? How are you tracking sessions (URL, Cookie or SSL)?

Comment: @MarkThomas what if the session has been invalidated or expired?  So, for instance the session ID is provided, but Tomcat has invalidated the session due to expiration?  If the F5 supplies an session Id at that point will it try to create a new session?

Comment: @MarkThomas It seems we are using cookies.

Comment: As long as the session has expired, the request should be mapped to the latest version. How are you determining that a new session is being created?

Comment: We were using the Tomcat Manager interface to look at created sessions for each application.  The creation session date for the older app was long after the new app had been deploy, almost a week older.

Comment: I've been through the source code and I can't see how this could happen. At this point, all I can suggest is adding an HttpSessionListener and logging the current stack trace during session creation.